# Why is my code throwing this error when converting to smali?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Java2Smali plugin for Android Studio. It has just started to fail when converting some of my jar files, even those which have been unchanged since last compile. I have tried everything I can think of and cant get it working.

Error im getting is:

```
org.jf.dexlib2.DexFileFactory$DexFileNotFoundException: StatusBarView.dex does not exist
at org.jf.dexlib2.DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(DexFileFactory.java:83)
at org.jf.dexlib2.DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(DexFileFactory.java:61)
at org.ollide.java2smali.Dex2SmaliHelper.disassembleDexFile(Dex2SmaliHelper.kt:24)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler$onProjectBuildComplete$1.run(DexCompiler.kt:67)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$runWriteCommandAction$5(WriteCommandAction.java:351)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:105)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:246)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:986)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:245)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:303)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:220)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:187)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:305)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:244)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:225)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.run(WriteCommandAction.java:107)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:351)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:343)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler.onProjectBuildComplete(DexCompiler.kt:66)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler.access$onProjectBuildComplete(DexCompiler.kt:22)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler$run$1.invoke(DexCompiler.kt:26)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler$run$1.invoke(DexCompiler.kt:22)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler$buildModule$1.accept(DexCompiler.kt:46)
at org.ollide.java2smali.DexCompiler$buildModule$1.accept(DexCompiler.kt:22)
at org.jetbrains.concurrency.AsyncPromise$onSuccess$1.accept(AsyncPromise.kt:84)
at org.jetbrains.concurrency.AsyncPromise$onSuccess$1.accept(AsyncPromise.kt:16)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
at org.jetbrains.concurrency.AsyncPromise.setResult(AsyncPromise.kt:149)
at com.intellij.task.impl.ProjectTaskManagerImpl$ResultConsumer.lambda$notify$1(ProjectTaskManagerImpl.java:351)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:328)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:132)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:188)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:499)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Google hasn't helped and I've run out of ideas. Help please.....

Comment: The very first message says, *`StatusBarView.dex` does not exist*. Is that a file provided by the library you obtained, or is it a file you have to provide? Looks like you need to start there.

Comment: This is the file I am trying to convert, it is written in java on my Android Studio, I have converted it a thousand times but no it and some others are not converting, while others have no issue.